# Name Change of Project Folder After installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directory, rename

[image]hi Friend
          i build project in Visual Studio when i install it .In start menu in folder name is exist.my question how change the folder name that project exist in it

Answer (score 0):

hi go in Solution Explore->your project Name at top right click and enter on Properties ->a window open in left corner go in Publish tab->in option menu click it->you see new window open Published Name and so on change it